# Count number of clicks in iframe implemented in shiny

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, shiny

i am very new with iframes. I am trying to implement a shiny code so that i can count the number pages I visit when implement an iframe from an online newspaper. So, i want to count how many time the iframe changes when clicking.

So far I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 12,
          HTML('
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
          <style>
            iframe{
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
            }
          </style>
          </head>
          <body>
              <script> var i =-1; </script>
              <iframe src="https://elpais.com/" onLoad="console.log(++i)"></iframe>

          </body>'),
          textOutput("view")
          )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderText( paste0( "User ID is: " ) ) 
  

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Every time I click a link, I can see the value of variable "i" in the Google chrome console. But I actually want to have acces to this value in my R code.
I have seen that you can acces js variables with shiny using shiny.oninputchange. Nevertheless I am very confused on how this should be implemented.

Thank you in advance if you can aswer my questions!

Comment: To me it's not clear what you are trying to achive. However, if you want to send data from JS to R use [Shiny.setInputValue](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html).

Answer (score 0):

I want to count the number of times I click on the iframe and the iframe page refreshes to a new one (for example, a diferent news item). I hope this answer helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry If the question was a little unclear. I finally solved it like this. Every time the iframe embedded in my shiny app refreshes I have a count that adds one to its value. This way I can count the number of pages I visit while navigating in my I frame. I do that by adding one to the count every time the page in the Iframe refreshes.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 12,
          HTML('<input type="text" id="count" name="count" style="display: none;"> '), 
          HTML('
          <style>
            iframe{
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
            }
          </style>
          </head>
          <body>
              <script> 
                var countStr = "count";
                var changeStr = "change";
                var countInput = document.getElementById(countStr);
                countInput.value = -1;
              </script>
              <iframe src="https://elpais.com/" onLoad="var event = new Event(changeStr);countInput.value++;countInput.dispatchEvent(event)"></iframe>

          </body>'),
          #includeScript("example/get_user_id.js"), 
          textOutput("view"),
          actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"),
          
          )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
    count <- reactive({ input$count }) 
    output$view <- renderText( paste0( "User ID is: ",count()) ) 
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```